# Need to access tty console while running kiosk mode with fbcon (Raspberry Pi 3B+)

Tags: raspberry-pi, tty, framebuffer

I am Running my application on Raspberry Pi 3B+ in kiosk mode. I successfully put my splash logo while it boots and display the boot messages by adding fbcon=map:2 in the file /boot/cmdline.txt. I also need to access the tty console which I enable it by ctrl+alt F2 (tty2) but it is not working on fbcon mode. Any suggestions ?

Comment: If it would it would defeat the purpose of kiosk mode, wouldn't it? So if you need that don't run it in kiosk mode?

Comment: Resolved the issue with command: con2fbmap 1 0